# cypress ignore timeout when using timeout

Tags: timeout, cypress

cy.get('#btnPulisciFiltri', {
timeout: 15000
}).should('be.visible').click()

use 15sec but cypress ignore this always have

CypressError Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element:

...

Answer (score 1):

It's referring to the `.click()` which has it's own timeout option

```js
cy.get('#btnPulisciFiltri', { timeout: 15000 })
  .should('be.visible')
  .click({ timeout: 15000 })
```

What is the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

Fody's answer is perfect for applying the timeout to only one command. If you wanted to apply the timeout globally, [you can set the timeout value in your `cypress.json`.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts)

```js
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 15000
}
```